# Why does horizontal scrollbar show up when I add a video with 100vw and 100vh?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a background video on the website I am currently making but for some reason, a horizontal scrollbar shows up when I add the background video. I am aware that it can disappear once I add overflow-x:hidden into my code but I was searching online and a good number of people said it is considered as bad practice. I also tried adding max-width:100% to the parent container but that also didn't help. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? I'll be using background-color in my code for reference.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.content1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content2 {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content1"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="content2"></div>
</div>
```

Notice how it has a horizontal scroll despite the width of my div to be 100vw. Would love it if someone can explain to me why the horizontal scroll appears and how it can be avoided without using overflow-x:hidden

Here's a picture of the horizontal scrollbar.
[image]

Comment: I'm not getting a horizontal scrollbar from your snippet (Safari / MacOS). Please add details as of where you are observing this.

Comment: Really? I am currently seeing a horizontal scrollbar using Microsoft Edge when I run it on a live server.

Comment: @connexo, Did you test this code in your local? Can't see the horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: @connexo I just updated my post and added a picture of the horizontal scrollbar I am seeing

Comment: don't use 100vw, use 100%

Comment: In some browsers, the viewport width includes the scroll bar. When using width: 100vw in browsers that are configured to show a full scroll bar, that evaluates to the width of the visible website plus the scroll bar width. But an element with that width is actually wider than what is visible in the browser's viewport.

Answer (score -3):

By default, most browsers add a margin to the body element, and it can cause the horizontal scrollbar to appear when using 100vw.

In some browsers, the viewport width includes the scroll bar. When using width: 100vw in browsers that are configured to show a full scroll bar, that evaluates to the width of the visible website plus the scroll bar width. But an element with that width is actually wider than what is visible in the browser's viewport.

To fix this, you can add the following CSS rule to remove the default margin from the body:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: The OP already removed the body margin.

Comment: `overflow-x: hidden` is mandatory.

Comment: The OP already knows that `overflow:-x: hidden` is an option but that is not the question. The question is WHY does this happen.

Comment: Removing overflow has a lot of hidden unwanted implications of all sorts. DON'T.